# pygame play many movies

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.6

i'm trying to play few videos.
And got error:

> python2.6: ../../src/xcb_io.c:183: process_responses: Assertion `!(req
>   && current_request && !(((long) (req->sequence) - (long)
>   (current_request)) <= 0))' failed.

I think some error in threads, and pygame movie player.

In documentation on pygame wrote:

> The video overlay planes are drawn on top of everything in the display
>   window. To draw the movie as normal graphics into the display window,
>   create an offscreen Surface and set that as the movie target. Then
>   once per frame blit that surface to the screen

Could give me example anybody?

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
background = pygame.Surface((1024, 768))

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

movie = pygame.movie.Movie('media/video.mpg')
mrect = pygame.Rect(0,0,140,113)
movie.set_display(screen, mrect.move(65, 150))
movie.set_volume(0)
movie.play()

mrect2 = pygame.Rect(0,0,140,113)
movie2 = pygame.movie.Movie('media/video2.mpg')
movie2.set_display(screen, mrect2.move(350, 150))
movie2.set_volume(0)
movie2.play()
```

Comment: Your code is fine so far. Which OS, pygame- and libxcb-version are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 10.10, pygame current version. This topic may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting both videos on the same screen, that might be the cause of a multi-tread error. Try defining new Surfaces for each movie and blit those on the screen